# iOS 16: PDFPage(image) throwing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, ios16

I am getting an error while calling `PDFPage(image)` in the following code in iOS 16:

```
extension PDFDocument {
    func flattened(withDPI dpi: CGFloat = 72) -> PDFDocument {
        let flattenedDocument = PDFDocument()
        for pageIndex in 0..<pageCount {
            let oldPage = page(at: pageIndex)
            var image = oldPage?.image(withDPI: dpi)
            if (image != nil) {
                //Error in following statement
                let flattenedPage = PDFPage(image: image!)
                if (flattenedPage != nil) {
                    flattenedDocument.insert(flattenedPage!, at: flattenedDocument.pageCount)
                }
            }
        }
        return flattenedDocument
    }
}
```

Error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

It is working fine for older versions of iOS (<16)

I tried removing alpha channel:

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func removeAlpha() -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.init()
        format.opaque = true //Removes Alpha Channel
        format.scale = scale //Keeps original image scale.
        let size = size
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { context in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}
```

and then calling:

```
...
var image = oldPage?.image(withDPI: dpi)
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
   image = image?.removeAlpha()
}
if (image != nil) {
...
```

But this resulted in this image instead (black big corners):
[image]

Comment: `image` is not `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
extension PDFPage {
    func image(withDPI dpi: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = true
        let pageRect = bounds(for: .mediaBox)
        let dpiRatio = dpi / 72  // Default DPI is 72
        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: dpiRatio, y: dpiRatio)
        let imageSize = pageRect.size.applying(scaleTransform)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageSize, format: format)
        return renderer.image { ctx in
            UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).setFill()
            ctx.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
            ctx.cgContext.saveGState()
            ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: imageSize.height)
            ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: dpiRatio, y: -dpiRatio)
            draw(with: .mediaBox, to: ctx.cgContext)
            ctx.cgContext.flush()
            ctx.cgContext.restoreGState()
        }
    }
}
   

extension PDFDocument {
    func flattened(withDPI dpi: CGFloat = 72) throws -> PDFDocument {
        let flattenedDocument = PDFDocument()
        for pageIndex in 0..<pageCount {
            let oldPage = page(at: pageIndex)
            var image = oldPage?.image(withDPI: dpi)
            if (image != nil && image?.cgImage != nil) {
                let flattenedPage = PDFPage(image: image!)
                if (flattenedPage != nil) {
                    flattenedDocument.insert(flattenedPage!, at: flattenedDocument.pageCount)
                }
            } else {
                throw PdfGenerationError.imageEmpty
            }
        }
        return flattenedDocument
    }
}
```

Use:

```
 do {
       try documentView.document?.flattened().write(toFile: documentPath!)
   } catch {
       displayToast(with: "Error. Please retry.")     
 }
```