# How do I avoid crash on PDFPage(image: image) with reason EXC_BAD_ACCESS (KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS) on iOS 16+

Tags: swift, pdfkit, ios16.4

Same code is working fine on below iOS 16, but crash was observed on higher versions.

Line of Code :

```swift
if let errorView = getErrorImageView(),
            let page = PDFPage(image: errorView) { // <- Crash Observed on this line.
            page.addAnnotation(getTitlePDFAnnotation())
            let count = pdfDocument?.pageCount ?? 0
            pdfDocument?.insert(page, at: count)
        }


fun getErrorImageView() -> UIImage? {
let errorView = UIView()
        errorView.bounds = view.bounds
        errorView.backgroundColor = .athenaWhite
        let errorTitleLabel = UILabel()
        errorTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        errorTitleLabel.text = "Error"
        errorTitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        errorView.addSubview(errorTitleLabel)
        // .... added constraint to view
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
        let image = renderer.image { _ in
            errorView.drawHierarchy(in: errorView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        return image
}
```

- Tried same code on different project, and it's working fine, but it's crashing on client project.
- Image is not nil
- Tried with image from xcasset
- Tried with removing alpha
- Tried with enabling zombie object

Crash Reason :

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

```
#0  0x000000012084d25f in CGBlitInternal::cgsBufferIsConstantValue_internal::TestLimits<unsigned char, 64ul>::operator()(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CGBlitInternal::cgsBufferIsConstantValue_internal::Limits const&) ()
#1  0x0000000120b89921 in bool CGBlitInternal::cgsBufferIsConstantValue_internal::TestLimitsRow<unsigned char>(void const*, unsigned long, CGBlitInternal::cgsBufferIsConstantValue_internal::Limits const&) (.10518) ()
#2  0x0000000120b8969d in bool CGBlitInternal::CGBufIsConstantValue<(CGBlitVariant)0>(CGBuf const*, float const*, float const*) ()
#3  0x0000000120ba7fe4 in is_image_alpha_opaque ()
#4  0x0000000120ba7bb8 in create_jpeg_copy ()
#5  0x0000000120bbd1df in pdf_DrawImage ()
#6  0x0000000120ad32b8 in CGContextDrawImageWithOptions ()
#7  0x00000001207e2ad2 in CGPDFPageCreateWithImage ()
#8  0x000000012b9c9e44 in +[PDFPage _createPageRefFromImage:andOptions:] ()
#9  0x000000012b9c38dd in -[PDFPage initWithCGImage:options:] ()
#10 0x000000012b9c476f in -[PDFPage initWithImage:options:] ()
#11 0x000000012b9c45ae in -[PDFPage initWithImage:] ()
#12 0x000000010502f913 in @nonobjc PDFPage.init(image:) ()
#13 0x0000000105025232 in PDFPage.__allocating_init(image:) ()
```

Most of similar code base : https://github.com/ShashikantBhadke/PDFKit_Crash_CodeBase

Comment: It's not the same method, but it could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474453/ios-16-pdfpageimage-throwing-exc-bad-instruction (same inner call)

Comment: Tried some steps but facing same crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your getErrorImageView() method with below code

```
fun getErrorImageView() -> UIImage? {
    let errorView = UIView()
    errorView.bounds = view.bounds
    errorView.backgroundColor = .white
    let errorTitleLabel = UILabel()
    errorTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    errorTitleLabel.text = "Error"
    errorTitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    errorView.addSubview(errorTitleLabel)
    // .... added constraint to view
    // Create a UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat and set its opaque as true
    let rendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
    rendererFormat.opaque = true
    // Now pass this rendererFormat to UIGraphicsImageRenderer
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size, format: rendererFormat)
    let image = renderer.image { _ in
        errorView.drawHierarchy(in: errorView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    return image
}
```

Since your crash log suggests on creating **`PDFPage`** it checks for **`is_image_alpha_opaque`** or not. And this provided image is not opaque it will crash.
Here since `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` now takes `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat` as input parameter.
We can utilise it's ability to for drawHierarchy where we have set its `opaque` property to true and doesn't updated any `alpha`.

I hope this will avoid the crash. Happy Coding ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround, to avoid Image opaque issue you need to first draw the image using a format that is opaque and uses a standard color range and then draw that new image in the PDF context.

```
// Re-draw image to adjust color range etc.
let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
format.preferredRange = .standard
format.opaque = true
format.scale = 1
let newImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size, format: format).image { _ in
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
}

// Draw in PDF context
newImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newImage.size))
```

Referenced from: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736607